# Cannot mount USB after I boot Kali on it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, kali

I wanted to install Kali linux as second OS so I boot it on USB. Then I found out that I cant resize my partition and I should first boot Ubuntu on USB and resize from 'Try Ubuntu' but when I tried to boot Ubuntu on the USB I got error.

[image]

I tried to format the USB but I cannot because I get the same error. I reboot but it didn't help. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

use **Gparted** in live Ubuntu USB to resize the partition  , or boot to ubuntu if you have ubuntu then type this at terminal `sudo apt-get install gparted` this will install Gparted then you can resize your partition . 
if you have windows open disk management then make a free space for Linux by shrinking any partition of yours and keep it **unallocated** space.
**Note:**  **make sure that your OS is not hibernated**

Comment: OK but what to do with my USB?

Comment: ohh Sorry maybe i miss understand you . open Gparted then format your USB then get the OS back